# NodeJS/Express - Cannot Read All Req.Headers

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, http-headers, backend

Building a simple ToDo app with ReactJs frontend and NodeJs/Express backend. I configured my frontend to include userId as a request header:

```
export default function authHeader() {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  
    if (user && user.accessToken) {
      // return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken }; // for Spring Boot back-end
      return {
          'x-access-token': user.accessToken,
          'userid': user.id
      };       // for Node.js Express back-end
    } else {
      return {};
    }
  }
```

This header is included with the Axios request:

```
// List all Group Members
listMembers() {
    return http.get(`/group`, { headers: authHeader() });
}
```

Consequently, I can see the headers in the request:

[image]

Part of my auth middleware references the access token:

```
verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers["x-access-token"];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({
      message: "No token provided!"
    });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Unauthorized!"
      });
    }
    req.userId = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};
```

The req.headers lines near the top is able to pull the token from header "x-access-token" with no problem. HOWEVER - for debug purposes, I have tried to pull the header userId value instead using *let token = req.headers["userid"];* but this simply comes back as undefined in my debug tools. Why can it pull x-access token header but not userId? My eventual goal is to refer to the req.header userId value in backend SQL queries, this is just a test.

Comment: Make sure you spell the variables correctly. otherwise it seems okay.

Comment: @Sardar - Thanks for the reply. So you see no reason from what's shown above why the userid value in the request headers is coming back as undefined?

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue but could not. I was able log userid on the console, So i believe the issue not with the naming convention nor express neither node js. May be it you debug tool or you are not using it correctly. Please specify more details about this debug tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended being a capitalization error somewhere in pipeline. @Sardar's comment was on the money, make sure everything is spelled correctly and matches case.